# Web browsers are not showing iOS devices video track

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-video

There are 2 users in one twilio room. One is on chrome browser and another is on ios device's safari browser. Audio track is working for both users. But chrome is not showing safari's video track but safari is showing chrome's video track. And I am using both H264 and VP8

Comment: Have you checked the information about Safari and H264 here? https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/developing-safari-11

Comment: @philnash yes I checked that information. It works for safari on mac but it does not work for safari on ios.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? You can [connect to iOS Safari using desktop Safari](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2015/02/remote-debugging-ios-safari-on-os-x-windows-and-linux/) to see what's going on.

Comment: @philnash There are no errors in the console. Only one warning which is on safari's console not on chrome's console. "This release of twilio-video.js includes experimental support for Safari 11 and newer. Support for safari is experimental because log.js:138"

Comment: Do you get the events for video published from the remote participant? Or is only the audio stream received?

Comment: @philnash On safari I got both video and audio events but on chrome I got only audio.

Comment: Oh, is the issue with Chrome on iOS?

Comment: @philnash No, this issue is with safari on iOS

Comment: But you said you're only getting audio in Chrome?

Comment: Yeah but I was using chrome on mac and safari on iOS. But I have fixed this issue. I was creating 2 LocalVideoTracks so after removing 2nd, chrome started showing safari's video track.

Comment: how did you solve this issue I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @DeepakSingh My issue was because of 2 local video tracks. So, I deleted the second local video track and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was because I was creating 2 local video tracks to display self preview. So after removing 2nd instance of localVideoTrack, it is working as expected.

Comment: can you add some details?
maybe i have the same thing going on - 
for the participant that has a iOS device i get only the audio track - no video track on my firefox desktop.

Answer (score 0):

i contacted the twilio support and they told me to change the room settings for `Video Codec` to `VP8` -
(before i had chosen `VP8 or h.264`)

that solved it in our case.

| parameter | Client 1 | Client 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SDK | twilio-video.js | twilio-video.js |
| SDK Version | 2.12.0 | 2.12.0 |
| Platform Name | iOS | Ubuntu (Kubuntu) |
| Platform Version | 14.4 | Unknown (20.04) |
| Device Model | iPhone | Other |
| Browser Name | Mobile Safari | Firefox |
| Browser Version | 14.0.3 | 86.0 |
| Browser Major | 14 | 86 |